# TDD with Episerver

Tags: .net, tdd, episerver

What is the best way to abstract the episerver infrastructure for easier testing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written a post about [TDD with EPiServer](http://marekblotny.blogspot.com/2009/03/tdd-with-episerver.html) recently.

Basically the idea is to use Model-View-Presenter design pattern to isolate as much logic as you can from asp.net runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this post will help: [EPiServer CMS 5 R2 and unit testing](http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Cristian-Libardo/Dates/2008/10/R2-and-unit-testing/)